# Injecting services into a CLI Symfony 4 App

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I've got a Symfony 4.2 app with a CLI script, calling a Command - which works just fine.

But in my command I'm trying to access the DB (via Doctrine).

The documentation suggests that I can just add a constructor to my Command with what I need and it'll get injected. Except, it's my code constructing the Command when I call:

```
$applicant->add(new \App\Command\MyCommand());
```

If I need to inject it, that's fine, but how do I get access to the service from my CLI script in that case?

Comment: Might need just a bit more code here.  Typically you would not be instantiating the command object yourself.  Does your app use the Symfony container?  If so then you might consider defining the command as a service which would allow injecting whatever it needs.  And then pulling the command from the container when you need it.

Comment: Don’t create commands (services) by yourself but fetch them from the container instead. If you are doing so they have to be marked as public, otherwise they will get removed from the container during the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read documentation 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html

> Registering the Command
>   Symfony commands must be registered as services and tagged with the console.command tag. If you're using the default services.yaml configuration, this is already done for you, thanks to autoconfiguration.
>
> Executing the Command
>   After configuring and registering the command, you can execute it in the terminal:
>
> `php bin/console app:create-user`
>   As you might expect, this command will do nothing as you didn't write any logic yet. Add your own logic inside the execute() method.

As you can see you can later call your commands via bin/console.
For command to have access to database you need to inject specific service, Im not in fan of injecting whole container, but here is an example for you
[Symfony 4: doctrine in command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48234418/symfony-4-doctrine-in-command)

Comment: Furthermore, since this wasn't obvious to me. Once the command is added as a service, you can then call it from bin/console. I was trying to initiate the command class from a separate PHP script.

Comment: Well you can actually do this like shown here :D https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html
But I think you need CLI approach.