# Creating symfony command extending controller

Tags: php, shell, symfony

I am writing a symfony console command which will be executable by using "php bin/console app:mycommand" (symfony documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#creating-a-command).

In my MyCommand class I need to use the getDoctrine-function, so I have to extend the controller, but I don't see a way how to do that. Any ideas?

Currently I get following error on CLI: Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDoctrine" of class "App\Command\MyCommand".

```php
<?php
  // src/Command/MyCommand.php
  namespace App\Command;

  use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
  use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

  use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

  class MyCommand extends Command
  {
    // the name of the command (the part after "bin/console")
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:mycommand';

    protected function configure()
    {

    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
      // Not working, producing mentioned error 
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to call that function? What makes you think you "have to extend the controller"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getDoctrine()` method is provided by the `ControllerTrait`, which in turn depends on the `ContainerAwareTrait` for the container injection. This however will pull additional services and methods that you won't need in a command so instead of injecting the whole container, the recommended approach is that you inject just the service you need, which in this case is the `ObjectManager` (`ObjectManager` is the common interface implemented both by the ORM and the ODM, if you use both or you just care about the ORM, you can use `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface` instead).

```
  <?php
  // src/Command/MyCommand.php
  namespace App\Command;

  use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
  use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

  use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

  class MyCommand extends Command
  {
    // the name of the command (the part after "bin/console")
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:mycommand';

    private $manager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        // Now you have access to the manager methods in $this->manager
        $repository = $this->manager->getRepository(/*...*/);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But now I am getting this error on execution. Why does that happen? The ObjectManager is imported. `Cannot autowire service "debug.argument_resolver.not_tagged_controller.inner": argument "$manager" of method "__construct()" has type "Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager" but this class was not found.`

Comment: @Ccenter Sorry, I forgot a namespace component. Hopefully it works now

Comment: With both namespaces in use, the mentioned error disappears. But I get following runtime error for `$em = $this->manager->getDoctrine()->getManager();`: `Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDoctrine" of class "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager".` What's missing? I Would like to understand that. 

Over and above that: I found a working solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48234418/symfony-4-doctrine-in-command

Comment: @Ccenter you don't need to call `getDoctrine()->getManager()` , `$this->manager` *is the* `EntityManager` already and you can call `getRepository()` directly.